# Getting date and time from SharePoint Server 2007 and throw it to Javascript variable

Tags: 2007, javascript

How to I get the date and time from SharePoint Server 2007 and pass this value as a Javascript variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to get it from SharePoint; use a content editor web part (CEWP) to get the date directly in JavaScript. Once you've dropped a CEWP on the page, click to add content, choose HTML > Edit HTML Source from the ribbon. Now put a JavaScript block in it: `<script type="text/javascript">....</script>`. For the block, use this example to display the date: http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/date-time/

Something as simple as `var d = new Date();` will fetch the current date as an object, but you'll have to use the example to format it the way you need.

If you need to fetch the server time, you can a) use the [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537247.aspx) to connect to the server via JavaScript; b) use some simple server-side code to fetch the system date on your master page or page layout and store it in a JavaScript variable:

```
var systemDate = new Date("<%= System.DateTime.Now %>");
```

Now you're using JavaScript client side and fetching the date from the system server side. You have it stored in a Date object in JavaScript so you can use the earlier example to manipulate it as needed. Ensure that [server-side code blocks are enabled in your web.config](http://www.etechplanet.com/blog/adding-server-side-code-blocks-%28c-or-vbnet%29-to-sharepoint-custom-pages.aspx) for this to work.

Comment: Thanks Alex, the reason why I asked the question is that from my understanding, JavaScript is a client language (do correct me if I am misunderstand) and so JavaScript report the date and time could be from the client machine rather from the server machine (do correct me if I misunderstand)

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: One thing I just noticed: I don't think the Client Object Model is available on SP2007. So best bet is to use Option B in code above. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Alex so much. I wish to use your Option B but our Server Administrator is so "paranoid" that he refused to enabled the server-side code blocks in the web.config. Is there other way to retrieve the server date and time?

Comment: Some options: If you need a date/time display mechanism, use a free web part, such as this: http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5729. Bamboo also has a free date/time web part. Another option: Create a list with a DateTime column; then set the date to today -- http://sridharu.blogspot.com/2009/01/set-default-date-time-to-datetime-field.html. In addition, you can add a calculated column to format the date anyway you need via formulas (http://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2009/05/02/common-date-time-formulas-for-sharepoint-calculated-fields/). Then drop the web part on your page.

Comment: Hi Alex, can I assume that the Date Time from calculated column are truly from the SharePoint 2007 Server itself and not from other places? (I was thinking to use this options as the last resort)

Comment: I believe so. You might need to verify it: Try this solution; change the date/time on your workstation and see what results you get.

Comment: Appreciate so much help given even though I wish to use your answer but because of our "paranoid" server administrator. Anyway, I mark your answer as my solution cause you given me so much ideas to retrieve the server time of the SharePoint server 2007. Thanks so much.